# #Visual Studio How to find a startup project in VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have given a C# solution from my company. There are too many projects inside in it. I know how to set a project as a startup project but seems like there is no question asking how to find a project that is specifically "startup" project.
please help me how to do this...

Thank you for reading.

Comment: There may even be multiple startup projects: the solution may contain several related apps

Comment: You were given that solution, can't you ask the person that gave it to you?

Comment: yes sure i can ask her for where is startup project. but i thought there must be a somthing button that tell us the project... since vs is a very large program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for startup project is a user setting, not a solution setting.  This means that your startup project may be different from mine for the same solution.  You probably need to configure the correct startup project once.

That said, there are a few clues to finding the current settings:

1. The Debug Target on the Standard toolbar might show it.  This might also show a different name if there are multiple startup targets defined for a given project.  The down arrow will show you all the startup targets for the selected project.

[image: Startup project called WebApplication1]

2. If your solution has multiple projects, right-click on it and select Set Startup Projects.  This will show you the current startup project(s) or let you configure your own settings.  (You can also get here by right-clicking and selecting Properties at the bottom, then find it under Common Properties -> Startup Project in the options hierarchy.)

[image: Solution right-click menu]

Comment: I'll add that you can also right click on the Solution Name in the Solution Explorer and find Set Startup Projects... as an option in that context menu as well.  Finally, you can right click on any executable Project in the Solution Explorer and Set as Startup Project should be an option in that context menu.